# Out of range error

Tags: excel, vba, variables

I am trying to activate numerous tabs named for example I have a tab named "95004700" I reference these codes in a list then seek to activate the corresponding tab (I set them = to the variable STRcode). For some reason I constantly get an out of range error at "worksheets(STRcode).Activate
"could someone explain to me why? I feel like it may have something to do with the formatting of the cell I am referencing or the method that I have set the variable with.

```
Sub Budget_Actual()

Dim DBLdatarow As Double
Dim STRcode As Long
Dim STRname As String
Dim cell As Range


    DBLdatarow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row - 1

    'loop #1
    Do While DBLdatarow > 5

        STRcode = Range("D" & DBLdatarow).Value
        STRname = Range("B" & DBLdatarow).Value

        Workbooks.Open Filename:="File Path"

                Worksheets(STRcode).Activate

                Columns("B:B").Select

                Set cell = Selection.Find(What:=STRname, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)


    DBLdatarow = DBLdatarow + 1
    Loop
    'loop #1

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply pass a string:

```
Worksheets(cstr$(STRcode)).Activate
```

As passing an integer attempts to open the 95004700th sheet (based on the fact that `Worksheets(1)` is another way of addressing the first sheet and  `Worksheets("1")` addresses a sheet *named* `"1"`).

Comment: I just tried it and it still gives me an error. What should I set the variable as?

Comment: The same error? `Worksheets(cstr$(95004700)).Activate` works for me

Comment: Yes that works, I have no problem activating the Tabs using their number, but there are a lot of them so I need to use a variable to reference them in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Sheets(STRcode).Activate activates Worksheet number STRcode. While you probably want to activate Worksheet with the name STRcode.

Excel can't handle 95004700 sheets.

You need to change STRcode from Integer to String.

Comment: there are not 95004700 sheets that is simply the name of the sheet, as each one requiers a unique code. there are about 25 sheets.

Comment: STRcode as string: => Sheets('95004700').Activate, which activates the sheet with the name 95004700.
rather than
STRcode as integer: => Sheets(95004700).Activate, as Excel tries to activate sheet number 95004700, which is of course out of range.